# Php annotation regexp

Tags: php, regex, json

I need to parse php docComment annotations with regexp. Possible annotations:

```
/**
 * @Annotation()
 * @Annotation\Name("var1", "var2")
 * @Annotation(["var1", "var2"], "var3")
 * @Annotation\Filter\Name(["var1", "var2"], "var3", {"var4": "var5"})
 */
```

Basically `@Annotation(<json>)`. In php I decode it like this `json_decode('['.$json.']')`

Now I use regexp `/@(\w+[\\\\\w+]*)\(([^\)]*)?\)/` but this is not always true. For example:

```
@Annotation("name()")
```

What regexp should I use?

Is it possible to parse more than one annotation in the line?

```
/**
 * @a() @b("var1")
 * ....
 */
```

**UPDATE:**

How to write this in regexp:

```
# match annotation name
# if brackets are empty 
    # match ()[space|newline]
# (else) if something is in brackets
    # match everything until:
        # ")[space|newline]
        # or })[space|newline]
        # or ])[space|newline]
```

**UPDATE 2**

What about this regexp `@((\w+)([\\\\\w+]*))(?:\(\s*\)|\((.*?["\}\]])(?:\s|$)*\))(?:\s|$)`. Can it be simplified?

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/zU1eQ5)

Comment: What about `(?:@Annotation)([^(]+)*\((.+)(?=\))`? You can access the json with $2 (second capture group) and optionally use $1 (first capture group) if you wanted to know `\Name` or `\Filter\Name` for example. I don't think it's possible to have content like `"name()"` AND have two annotations on a line though. This RegEx works for your content types but not for multiline annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify it to:

```
@([\\\w]+)\((.*)\)
```

[Live demo #1](http://regex101.com/r/iF0bY6)

***Update 3***

For more annotations in one line:

```
@([\\\w]+)\((.*?)\)(?:\s|$)
```

[Live demo #2](http://regex101.com/r/gM7wS7)

***Update 4***

Based on your last edit:

```
@([\\\w]+)\((?:|(.*?[]"}]))\)
```

[Live demo #3](http://regex101.com/r/tW6pI4)

Comment: `@Annotation("name@name.com")` will fail

Comment: is it possible to match `@Annotation("name()")` and `@Annotation("name@name.com")`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your regexp is almost what I want, but `@Annotation("name() ", "aaa")` will fail. See my question update :)

Comment: @Tomas Check my update. Ain't you going to remember something more?! ;)

Comment: Thanks @revo for your time and knowledge. You helped me a lot.